# Is bitset faster than an array of bools?

Tags: c++

C++ provides the [`bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) to store bits. As per the reference, the class emulates an array of `bool` elements, but optimized for space allocation. In which cases one should be preferred to the other?

Comment: Why do not not write some code to get performance statistics?

Comment: Good question. You should benchmark your problem using both implementations.

Comment: @juanchopanza: You are right, the question should be: when should I prefer one or the other. I'll edit

Comment: @AmiTavory: it's a general question. I heard about this classes that I didn't know today, and I wanted to expand my toolbox. If one implementation is much different from another, I would like to know.

Answer (score 7):

The right thing is to take measurements.

Nonetheless, as I recall, docs about bitsets always said that a bit set is not guaranteed to be real bits, it's just a recommendation for the compiler and a convenient syntax for bits manipulation.

On embedded systems compilers, many use real bitsets because working with bits is a real necessity in such a kind of programs.

As for speed, the opposite is more reasonable - working with arrays is simpler by means of indexing. Working with bits requires more math, to access the correct word and then access the correct bit.

Comment: While "bitshifts mean extra work, so it must be slower!" sounds reasonable, in practice the additional cost is two additional shifts, and two ands (at most). That's about 2 cycles on modern CPUs. But you just increased the memory pressure eight-fold which can have much, *much* bigger consequences on performance. So it's by far not as clear-cut.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question so I made a benchmark for searching a sequence. Because bitset doesn't have iterators I had to make a "std::search" alternative for bitset.

c-lang 8.0 results:

```
64 bits => bitset 1.2 times slower than array
128 bits => bitset 1.4 times slower than array
1024 bits => bitset 1.5 times slower than array
4096 bits => bitset 1.5 times slower than array
```

gcc 9.1 results:

```
64 bits => bitset 1.6 times faster than array
128 bits => bitset 1.5 times faster than array
1024 bits => bitset 1.4 times faster than array
4096 bits => bitset 1.4 times faster than array
```

Total unexpected results.

The benchmark can be run here http://quick-bench.com/-er6qDrx0dPmJ0rGnJ9t3EpLoMM

**Update 2020-09**

Using Clang 10.0 and GCC 10.1, in both cases the **array of bools is faster than bitset**.

Answer (score 2):

You need to benchmark your use case.

- conventional implementation of `bitset<N>` is using bit-per-element and `array<bool, N>` -- byte-per-element, so the former has higher changes to fit in L1d..LLd, and may thus be faster for critical size bitmask, at least when performing serial access
- `bitset<N>` does more math so under some access patterns (highly random) may well be slower
- when accessed concurrently, `array<bool, N>` would have less contention per element, so performance would depend a lot on the access pattern.

---

#### Addition 2020.09

I routinely use `uint64_t`-s directly and compiler intrinsics to scan/count.
It beats both the alternatives the OP has asked about for use cases where it can be used (well, for tracking of up to 64 of something).