# C++ UE4 - bool vs. uint8 : 1 vs. uint32 : 1 - pros and cons of each?

Tags: c++, integer, boolean, unreal-engine4, bitmask

So, I'm familiar with the concept of packing a bunch of Boolean values using a single bit inside of an integer (bit masking I think its called), and thus you conserve memory because a Boolean is a byte and you fit more than one Boolean in an byte long integer. Thus, if you have enough Booleans, packing them together can make a big difference, and we see that in the native Unreal source code this particular optimization is used quite heavily. What I'm not clear on however, is what are the downsides of this? There are places where many regular Booleans are used instead. Also, why in some paces are uint32 used and some places unint8 are used? I've read there may be some read write related inefficiencies or something?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812572/is-bitset-faster-than-an-array-of-bools

Comment: In general the expensive part is passing data from your cpu to the gpu and vice versa. Therefore when this happens it is very likely to use bitmasking (packing multiple boolean values into one byte). The downside of this is readability. Having a single boolean variable for everything makes it less likely for a developer to accidentially grab the wrong value, so in places where it is not critical separate booleans can be preferred.

Comment: Note: The compiler won't combine different types of bits to save space.  If you have a uint8 and a uint64, that's 9 bytes, not 8.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem is that there is no pointer to "packed bool" - like you have an int32 that packs 32 booleans then you cannot make `bool*` or `bool&` that refers to any of them in a proper way. This is due to the fact that byte is a minimal memory unit.

In STL they made `std::vector<bool>` that saved space and had the same interface semantically as other vectors. To do so they had to make special proxy class that is returned from `operator []` so one do stuff like `boolVec[5] = true`. Unfortunately, this over-complication resulted in many problems in performance and usage of `std::vector<bool>`.

Even simple instructions on packed booleans tend to be composite and thus heavier than if the booleans represented via `bool` and took a whole byte. Additionally, modifying values of packed boolean is could be causing data-racing in multi-threaded environment.

Basically, hardware simply doesn't support booleans too well.

Next, image POV of OS designer and you create common interface of shared libraries (aka dll). How to treat booleans now? Byte is a minimal memory unit so to pass a single boolean one would still need to use at least a single byte. So why not simply forget about existence of bool and simply pass it via a single byte? So we don't even need to implement this needless type of bool and it will save lots of time for all compiler writers of all languages.

`uint8` vs `uint32`; Also, note that Windows' COM (component object model - not serial port) uses `int16` for boolean. In general, it is inherently unimportant as when passing values to a shared library's function that does complex stuff will not make any noticeable difference in performance as you are already calling a much heavier function.  Still why is it so? I imagine they had some reasons a long time ago when they designed it and everybody has already forgotten why and they simply keep it unchanged as changing it will result in complete disaster in terms of backwards compatibility.

In C99 `_Bool` was introduced for booleans but it is just a different name for an unsigned int. I imagine from this originated usage of `uint32` for booleans. In general, `int` is supposedly the most efficient integer type in terms of performance (which it why its size is not strictly defined) - so the C committee chose the supposedly most efficient type to represent booleans.